# C# Generic Programming - combining these classes

Tags: c#, generics

First up, some sample code (simplified), because if you're like me, you want to inspect the code rather than trying to read me trying to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
interface IA
{
    void MyMethod1();
    void MyMethod2();
    void MyMethod3();
    void MyMethod4();
    void MyMethod5();
}

interface IB
{
    void MyMethod1();
    void MyMethod2();
    void MyMethod3();
    void MyMethod4();
    void MyMethod5();
    void MyMethod6();
}

abstract class XA: IA
{
    public XA(IA[] As) { m_As = As; }

    public virtual void MyMethod1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod4()
    {
        m_As[0].MyMethod1();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod5()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected IA[] m_As;
}

abstract class XB: IB
{
    public XB(IB[] Bs) { m_Bs = Bs; }

    public virtual void MyMethod1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod2()
    {
        m_Bs[0].MyMethod6();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod4()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod5()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod6()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected IB[] m_Bs;
}

class XXA: XA
{
    XXA(IA[] As): base(As) { }

    public override void MyMethod1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod4()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod5()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MyOtherMethod1() { }
    public void MyOtherMethod2() { }
}

class XXB: XB
{
    XXB(IB[] Bs) : base(Bs) { }

    public override void MyMethod1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod4()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod5()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void MyMethod6()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MyOtherMethod3() { }
    public void MyOtherMethod4() { }
}
```

We see here a lot of duplicated code. I'm trying to figure out a good way to reduce this code and remove duplicated code. More on that below...

IB is essentially a superset of IA, but IB does not inherit from IA because IB should NOT be used where IA can be used.

Then we have XA and XB. XB is essentially just an XA with some added functionality. Again, can't inherited from XA because XB is NOT an XA.

Furthermore, we see that XA has some member state of type IA. It depends on this member state being of this interface, so the class cannot be templated (Is that the right word?).

Because XA depends on member state, there is the possibility to break out SOME functionality that does not rely on member data (i.e. m_As), but honestly, if it does not, then what's the point of it being a member function? Well, I guess if there's some other state that's not of type IA that might work, but it feels like a hack since some code is factored out while others is not.

Being familiar with C++, in that language I'd simply make XA a template class with IA being a template parameter. But I can't do that in C#, can I? So anyone know of a good solution for this mess?

Thanks!

Since people have asked, I'm trying to make a pattern matcher, so I have these two interfaces:

```
interface IPattern
{
    void UpdateIfMatch(String Line, bool Trim = true);
    void Reset();
    bool IsMatch();
    bool IsFound();
}

interface IDeletePattern
{
    void UpdateIfMatch(String Line, bool Trim = true);
    void Reset();
    bool IsMatch();
    bool IsFound();
    bool ShouldDelete();
}
```

IDeletePattern is special because it uses a function ShouldDelete() to tell the user of the class when a specific line that's matched by a specific pattern should be deleted or not (should I make an example?). If I uses IDeletePattern where an IPattern is expected, I would lose the ShouldDelete() functionality which the whole point about this interface, so that's a no-no.

Therefore, I separate these two interfaces. But all classes that implements these interfaces share a lot of implementation detail, so I want to share them as much as possible. But when I've tried to do so, I've run into the scenario above.

I can post full code, but that will be very messy.

Comment: Your attempts at obscuring the code, made it really unreadable. Any chance you could think of a simple, real-life scenario that would match your problem and name the classes/interfaces accordingly?

Comment: Your B class [contains functionality](http://enoshtechdiary.blogspot.ru/2012/04/composition-vs-aggregation.html) of your A class, isn't it?

Comment: You don't have duplicated code, you have duplicated implementations of two interfaces that have the same names.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the problem is, but maybe a [generic interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx) can help?

Comment: decPL: I could post my current code, but I find that more of a mess than this simple example.

Vadim: Yes, it does, because they work in similar ways, but have different tasks.

John: True, the implementation is duplicated, and that's what I want to avoid. Much of it could be shared.

Dialecticus: I'll take a look.

Comment: XA,XXA,XB,XXB,IA,IB is very tough to read. Use your code but limit the depth of the method body. In all honestly I really don't understand the question. At first glance there seems to be "A fat interface" issue. Limit the core Interface members to one then implement from that accordingly. Then create Interfaces that correspond to independent class's.

Comment: I don't think we can help you unless we can see what exactly is inside all the X classes.

Comment: Right now, it seems to me C#'s type system is not good enough to have proper deduplication of code, while maintaining all the constraints.

Comment: @Athena, what if you extend `interface IPattern` with `bool CanExecute()` method? Then `interface IDeletePattern` will be not necessary; implementations of `IPattern` will have to decide if they can be executed (`return true;` by default, probably?). Those who use `IPattern` will be able to check it too

Answer (score 1):

This is an initial answer:

Why you just use abstract class called **X** that has the abstract methods, and each **XA,XB** override the abstracted methods, and in same time implement the interfaces, and keep you **XXA** inherit from **XA**, and **XXB** inherit from **XB**.

Update: After I saw the actual code, you can use **Interface Segregation**

Like this:

```
interface IPattern
{
    void UpdateIfMatch(String Line, bool Trim = true);
    void Reset();
    bool IsMatch();
    bool IsFound();
}

interface IDeletePattern : IPatten
{    
    bool ShouldDelete();
}
```

Comment: Or you saw my comment ;)

Comment: This is what I want to avoid since that means I can use IDeletePattern wherever I can use an IPattern. But I could probably separate the common parts of IPattern and IDeletePattern into another interface (and never use that interface directly anywhere in the code).